# How do I get closedxml.excel to recognize merged cells?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to make a template excel file and I need to put data at various parts of the file. I have 2 fields where the data I'm importing is from a list so in the cell I do something like this:

```
{Item.Name}
```

and I of course name the range of cells that will be populated by this list. I have run into an issue where only the first record in my list will be of the correct format/ cell merge. Every record after the first completely breaks down all of my merged cells so my formatting is not good. Any ideas of how to get closedxml.excel to recognize there are merged cells?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a way to get only the merged cells, but you can check if a cell is merged:

```
using (var excelFileStream = new FileStream("excelfile.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using IXLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(excelFileStream);

    IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Worksheet(1);

    IXLCell cell = worksheet.Cell(row: 1, column: 1);
    IXLRangeAddress range = cell.MergedRange().RangeAddress;

    if (range.ColumnSpan > 1 || range.RowSpan > 1)
    {
        //merged cell
    }
    else
    {
        //non-merged cell
    }
}
```